# Docker invalid referenct format

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Runing this one Ubuntu 20 . What is wrong?
Using this tutorial
https://docs.vyos.io/en/latest/installation/virtual/docker.html

```
#docker run -d --rm --name vyos --privileged -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules > vyos:1.4-rolling-202112080318 /sbin/init
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: The `>` seems fishy. Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: One moment. BTW I have updated the description with tutorial link that I am using

Comment: @Turing85 yeah that worked... Looks like I misunderstood the step) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [tutorial (`docs.vyos.io`)](https://docs.vyos.io/en/latest/installation/virtual/docker.html) uses the following command:

```
docker run -d --rm --name vyos --privileged -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
> vyos:1.4-rolling-202111281249 /sbin/init
```

Notice the `\` at the end of the first line. This signals a multi-line command, i.e. the command is continued on the next line. The `>` at the beginning of the 2nd line is a prompt, i.e. not essential for the command. We can rewrite the command, e.g. as oneliner:

```
docker run -d --rm --name vyos --privileged -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules vyos:1.4-rolling-202111281249 /sbin/init
```

Or - what I like to do - put each parameter on a separate line:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  --rm \
  --name vyos \
  --privileged \
  -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
  vyos:1.4-rolling-202111281249 \
  /sbin/init
```

All of those are equivalent.

Comment: YEs that is correct. It is jsut I was not aware of ">" part . Thanks